# Accessing dict of inherited class variables in derived class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Suppose we have a base class, `A`, that contains some class variables. This class also has a class method `foo` that *does something* with those variables. Since this behavior shouldn't be hard-coded (e.g. we don't want to have to modify `foo` when adding new class variables), `foo` reads `cls.__dict__` instead of directly referencing the variables.
Now we introduce a derived class: `B` extends `A` with some more class variables, as well as inherits `foo`. Code example:

```py
class A:
  x = 0
  y = 1
  @classmethod
  def foo(cls):
    print([name for name, prop in cls.__dict__.items() if type(prop) is int])

class B(A):
  z = 3

print(B.x)  # prints "0"
A.foo()     # prints "['x', 'y']"
B.foo()     # prints "['z']" -- why not "['x', 'y', 'z']"?
```

Therefore, my question is: why `B.__dict__` does not contain the variables inherited from `A`, and if not there, then where are they?

This is not a duplicate of [Accessing class attributes from parents in instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52532937/6919631), because I don't just want to *query* specific variables that happen to be in the base class - I want to *list them* without knowing their names. The answers related to MRO given in this question might happen to also apply here, but the original problem is in my view different.

Comment: They are in `A.__dict__` of course. If you *really* want to do this, then you are going to have to iterate through the `mro` explicitly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing class attributes from parents in instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532937/accessing-class-attributes-from-parents-in-instance-methods)

Comment: In that proposed duplicate, it is dealing with an instance method, but it should be easy to modify dealing with the classmethod, just careful with name clashes, so something like `[name for kls in cls.mro() for name, prop in vars(kls).items() if isinstance(prop, int)]`

Comment: This solution with MRO works, thank you. I will post my alternative approach using a metaclass, which I ended up using because it gives me some additional benefits (unrelated to the original question).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/6919631), using it to redefine the way derived classes are created. In this approach, all class variables that we are interested in get *copied* from the base classes to the derived one:

```py
class M(type):
  def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
    for base in bases:
      for name, prop in base.__dict__.items():
        if type(prop) is int:
          dct[name] = prop
    return super(M, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class A(metaclass=M):
  x = 0
  y = 1
  @classmethod
  def foo(cls):
    print([name for name, prop in cls.__dict__.items() if type(prop) is int])

class B(A):
  z = 3

A.foo()  # prints "['y', 'x']"
B.foo()  # prints "['y', 'x', 'z']"
```

Besides, the metaclass can be defined in such a way that `foo` will not even have to query the `__dict__` - variables of interest could be put into a list instead of modifying `__dict__`, should this for some reason had to be avoided.